# What encryption strategy should I use

Tags: javascript, firebase, encryption

I'm building a note taking app.
I want to reinsure my users that their data is encrypted when it is stored online (Firebase Firestore) and that no one except them can read it.
I want the app to stay simple so no login, no password (for now).

I'm thinking of using crypto-js to do the job. It supports many different encryption types. The one I'm looking at is AES:

```
// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');

// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

AES works with a secret key. What I wanna do is generate and store that secret key on the client side, Encrypt the data before it leaves to the internet, and decrypt the data anytime it comes back.

#### My questions are

- Is there any other encryption type that would fit the requirements better? the notes are potentially going to be big chunks of text. Does AES do well in those cases?
- Does this strategy even make sense? Apparently Firestore already encrypts the data, but since there's no login, anyone with the object id can read it (and the admin - me - can poke into the database and read sensitive data)

Comment: If the JavaScript will be running in the browser, people may be able to reverse it to decode the data anyway.  The documentation does describe access controls for Firestore - that's where I would start.

Comment: there's no reason to use a lib, go native: https://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because designing a full security protocol is not a concise programming related question.